# Why is my server receiving a byte array and not a string? TCP

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, buffer

So I have a client which I don't have access to the source code of, the client is super basic though, it connects to my server, sends a string that looks something like this `A8745783-K8757853` to my client.

Then my code receives it like this:

[image]

How do I store it as a string that looks like this `A8745783-K8757853` I want my received hold the value of `A8745783-K8757853`and not `A/06/05/02/06..`

I am not sure why my server is storing it like that, that's what I am wondering and how do I properly receive a buffer as a string?

```
public class Connection
{
        private const int Port = 12345;

        public static List<string[]> CardList = new List<string[]>();
        public static List<string[]> UserList = new List<string[]>();
        public static List<string[]> ReceivedList = new List<string[]>();

        //Make them private because we don't want to mess with these, it's "almost" like having them in a const form.. Keyword "Almost".
        private static readonly IPAddress Ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        private static TcpListener _listener;
        private static TcpClient _client;
        private static NetworkStream _nwStream;

        public static int BytesAmount;
        public static byte[] Buffer;

        public Connection()
        {
            _listener = new TcpListener(Ip, Port);
        }

        public static string User { get; set; }
        public static string Card { get; set; }

        public static string UserData { get; set; }
        public static string Received { get; set; }

        public async Task StartListenAsync()
        {
            _listener.Start();

            // This will sit in idle, waiting for a connection..
            Console.WriteLine("Listening..");

            // Assign the first connection to the client obj, we're doing this async.
            _client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            _nwStream = _client.GetStream();

            if (_client.Connected)
                Console.WriteLine("Client has connected!");

            // Keep listening for incoming data and split it.
            while (true)
                if (_nwStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    //long i = _nwStream.Length;
                    //Console.WriteLine(i);

                    Buffer = new byte[_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    BytesAmount = _nwStream.Read(Buffer, 0, _client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    Received = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer, 0, BytesAmount);

                    string something = Received;

                    // Our IDE (Visual Studio (VS) knows to make this into a string array because we're calling split on a string
                    // So to not make it redundant we'll be fine by doing new[] which in this case represents a new string array)
                    var splitArray = Received.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    User = splitArray[0].Replace(" ", "");
                    Card = splitArray[1].Replace(" ", "");

                    Console.WriteLine("Testing 1: " + User);
                    Console.WriteLine("Testing 2: " + Card);

                    Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Received);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + Received);
                    _nwStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesAmount);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you see that the unknown program sends you the string `A8745783-K8757853`? Can you use Wireshark to confirm what's actually sent in the TCP stream? Maybe the client does some further transformations on the received byte sequence, or interprets it in a different encoding?

Comment: How certain are you taht the string is in UTF8? Maybe it is UTF 16, so you have additiona leading/trailing Zeroes? Or maybe it is a Codepage from the last century? If you do not know for certain waht the encoding is, you can not interpret the string. Or even figure out where it ends: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: The client that sends the string was given to me by my teacher, I've been checking this with me teacher and he was that it was probably the way my way of receiving the bytes that could be the issue

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's spelled correctly **to receive / received** (not "to recieve / recieved")

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the encoding, I ad to use

```
Unicode
Recieved = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Buffer, 0, BytesAmount);
```

Instead of UTF8

Comment: So you say *although @Christopher is correct, I prefer to answer myself instead of honoring him*